# python 3 tcp server and client string transfer error

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I try to develop a simple server and client program, I run the code with python 3.4.2.( on Debian 8.6 ) . The server run well, the client program connect's to the server but when I pass a text in terminal to send to server and send back with time stamp, I get this error in the client terminal window

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "tcp_client", line 15, in 
>       tcpCliSock.send(data)
>   TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

### this is the server code

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime

HOST = '192.168.0.141'
PORT = 21577
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while True:
    print('waiting for connection...')
    tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
    print('....connected from :', addr)

    while True:
        data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not data:
            break
        tcpCliSock.send('[%s] %s' % (bytes(ctime(), 'utf-8'), data))
    tcpCliSock.close()

tcpSerSock.close()
```

### and this it the client code

```
from socket import *

HOST = '192.168.0.141'
PORT = 21577
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)

while True:
    data = input('> ')
    if not data:
        break
    tcpCliSock.send(data)
    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))

tcpCliSock.close()
```

Comment: the client cote have the host setup as the server ( HOST = '192.168.0.141' )

Comment: Please place your comment into the question as an edit, the entire post/question looks cleaner that way and becomes easier to understand.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will do that in future questions

Comment: I test the code on windows and I get the same result